# Select element from nodelist by attribute value

Tags: javascript

I am making an interactive floor map. It consists of multiple `rect` elements, which i get with `const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("rect")`. Each element has `id` attribute. I also have a dictionary, which i get from `ajax` response.

```
status = {
  "id": "status"
  ...
}
```

I need to make a function to update all rect elements with appropriate class:

```
function updateStatus(status){
      const object = status;
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
        // here i need to do something like nodeList.element[id=key].classList.add(value)
      };
    };
```

What is the correct way to do `nodeList.element[id=key].classList.add(value)`?

**UPDATE**

I first get a nodelist with `const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("rect");`. Then i send it to the server via `ajax`, which returns a dictionary with `id : status` pairs.
Now i need too update each node in `nodeList` with appropriate class based on the `status` from the dictionary. But all of it is not important, because my only question is **how to select a node based on its attribute value**. Basically i need to know how to do `document.querySelectorAll('rect[id="key"]');` not on the whole `document` but on the `nodeList` i already have.

Comment: I don't believe you get DOM nodes via AJAX, so are your nodes inside that `nodeList` variable? Inside `nodeList.element` ? Shoudn't it be plural?

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't really follow the question; can you add enough of your "*[mcve]*" (HTML, JavaScript and CSS) code that we can reproduce your problem, and explain what the "appropriate class" is, and what the end-result you're hoping for might be?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('rect[id="key"]');
[].forEach.call(nodes, el => el.classList.add(value));
```

Node: the `id` attribute should have unique values, therefore you shouldn't need to query a nodelist and iterate over it.